# AWS Lambda - Not able to access internet when tagged to VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that makes a REST call. While developing, I had tagged it to "No VPC" and it was working. Since, the function needed to talk to RDS, I had to tag to VPC that hosted RDS. Since then REST call is not working.

I followed the article -

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/

1. The VPC is tagged to default security group. The security group has both inbound and outbound allowed
2. The VPC has 6 subnets. 5 are named as private subnet and 1 is named as public subnet
3. The public subnet is linked to public router which is linked to internet gateway
4. All the 5 subnets are linked to private router that is linked to NAT Gateway
5. ACLs have both inbound and outbound allowed
6. The lambda function was linked to two private subnets

When I try my lambda function, it still doesnt work.
Further analysis revealed that NAT gateway is linked to ENI-XXXXX through elastic IP. When I check the inbound and outbound rule for ENI-XXX, there is nothing listed. When I tried to change the security group, I received - You do not have permission to access the specified resource. Please note, I was trying to change it through root account

I tried creating a Elastic IP, and tagged it to existing eni-xxx that has inbound and outbound rule. However I am not able to link it to new NAT(the new NAT fails with message that EIP is already associated). If I again create a new NAT Gateway, it creates a new ENI-XXXX which has no inbound or outbound and I dont find option of linking new NAT to an ENI that has inbound and outbound rule.

Has anyone faced this issue? Please let me know where am I going wrong?

Comment: It would be useful, if people can give reason behind down-voting the question. Or is their a way to find out?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggled this too and resolved by this:

1. Create a NAT gateway into the public subnet, then it will be linked to public IP.
2. Now, go to the Routing table in the VPC service and create it.

   - Linked subnets should be the private subnets of lambda.
   - destination to your VPC as local
   - destination to 0.0.0.0/0 as NAT gateway what you created a bit ago.
3. Test your lambda.

I didn't touch any ENI things.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I linked the same NAT gateway to the public subnet. However it didn't work.

Comment: @TusharSaurabh Linking is not to the public but your lambda subnet.